# Substituting existing variable into integral

Tags: integration, substitution

I'm trying to understand how this [solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6UFV.jpg) solves [this question part ii)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xOLU.png).
The solution does a substitution of $y=\pi -x$ into $\int^\pi_0 x f(\sin x) dx$
This substitution results in 
$$ \int^\pi_0 x f( \sin x)dx = \pi \int^\pi_0 f(\sin y) dy - \pi \int^\pi_0 y f(\sin y)dy$$

Then the author simply substitutes y = x to get :
$$ \int^\pi_0 x f( \sin x)dx = \pi \int^\pi_0 f(\sin x) dx - \pi \int^\pi_0 y f(\sin x)dx$$
Which becomes
$$ 2\int^\pi_0 x f( \sin x)dx = \pi \int^\pi_0 f(\sin x) dx $$

Doesn't subbing $y = x$ contradict the initial substitution of $y = \pi - x$ ? I've looked through my u-substitution textbook and nothing like this comes up. If someone could explain to me what this concept is called plus other examples of it, that would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Does [this](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DummyVariable.html) help?

Answer (score 1):

A note in the solution you have provided refers to something called a *dummy variable*.  For example, any integral that can be written in the form $$\int_a^b f(\lambda)\,d\lambda$$ will have the same value (and $\lambda$ can be *any* variable).

Therefore, in your solution, we have \begin{align}
\int_0^\pi xf(\sin x)\,dx&=\int_\pi^0(\pi-y)f(\sin(\pi-y))(-1)\,dy\\
&=\int_0^\pi (\pi-y)f(\sin y)\,dy\\
&=\pi\int_0^\pi f(\sin \color{blue}{y})\,d\color{blue}{y}-\int_0^\pi \color{blue}{y}f(\sin \color{blue}{y})\,d\color{blue}{y}\\
\int_0^\pi xf(\sin x)\,dx&=\pi\int_0^\pi f(\sin \color{blue}{x})\,d\color{blue}{x}-\int_0^\pi \color{blue}{x}f(\sin \color{blue}{x})\,d\color{blue}{x}\\
2\int_0^\pi xf(\sin x)\,dx&=\pi\int_0^\pi f(\sin x)\,dx\\
\int_0^\pi xf(\sin x)\,dx&=\frac\pi2\int_0^\pi f(\sin x)\,dx\\
\end{align}
as desired.

Comment: thanks for the reply. ah ok so it's called a dummy variable. am i right to say that this only works because this is a definite integral? it reminds me of how when we use u-substitution for definite integrals, we don't need to u = x because the final result doesn't have x in it. if we used a indefinite integral, it wouldn't work? eg. $$\int \cos x (\sin x)^2 dx $$ sub x = sin x $$\int \cos x (\sin x)^2 dx \neq \int x^2 dx$$
because we have no bounds

Comment: Yes; this is not necessarily true in indefinite integration.